# ImageURL issue with TMdb?

Tags: java, android, json

I'm writing a program (for learning purposes). Its basically a recyclerView showing popular movies from TMdb. Everything works fine but my main issue is that Json code from the API shows ImageURL or "Poster_path" like this:

```
"page":1,
   "results":[
      {
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/srYya1ZlI97Au4jUYAktDe3avyA.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[
            14,
            28,
            12
         ],
         "id":464052,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Wonder Woman 1984",
         "overview":"Wonder Woman comes into conflict with the Soviet Union during the Cold War in the 1980s and finds a formidable foe by the name of the Cheetah.",
         "popularity":2942.16,
         "poster_path":"/8UlWHLMpgZm9bx6QYh0NFoq67TZ.jpg",
         "release_date":"2020-12-16",
         "title":"Wonder Woman 1984",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":7.1,
         "vote_count":2853
      },
```

Sadly I can't see the poster in my app, and I'm using Glide to display the poster. Anyone can help me?
by the way how can I paste Json here? it is not formatted as you can see?

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for formatting help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. first check if your are adding the complete URL for the image, it should be
   "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/srYya1ZlI97Au4jUYAktDe3avyA.jpg"
2. try using Picasso Library,
   add the dependency for Picasso:

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.0'

and add the code for recyclerview as follows:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(IMAGE_PREFIX + movie.getImagePath()).resize(500,500)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.movieplaceholder2)
            .into(holder.movieImage);
```

Comment: I added full address now it works! Thanks!

Comment: I'm new to this, just out of curiosity, why do you recommend Picasso over Glide?